# SOLR Update a new field to exist document(use python3, scorched)

Tags: python-3.x, solr

I have trouble in update the fields in **solr-4.10**
Assume that I have the doc below:

```
"docs": [
  {
    "id": "2001354750",
    "post": [
      "小马也疯狂------地位之争。"
    ],
    "_version_": 1560655968803487700
  },
  {
    "id": "2001187260",
    "post": [
      "北京的小纯洁们，周日见。#硬汉摆拍清纯照#"
    ],
    "_version_": 1560655968822362000
  }
]
```

but I want to add field cmnt into doc like below:

```
"docs": [
  {
    "id": "2001354750",
    "post":"小马也疯狂------地位之争。",
    "cmnt":"Really?",
    "_version_": 1560655968803487700
  },
  {
    "id": "2001187260",
    "post": "北京的小纯洁们，周日见。#硬汉摆拍清纯照#",
    "cmnt":"Shy",
    "_version_": 1560655968822362000
  }
]
```

But I use

```
   import scorched
si = scorched.SolrInterface("http://localhost:8983/solr/chatbot")
document = {"id" : ID,
            "post" : arg
            }
si.add(document)
si.commit()
```

`ID` is a unique key, but when I run the code above,
if `ID` are same, it will cover my original data.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using curl with /update

Example:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8983/solr/collection_name/update -d '
[
 {"id"         : "2001187260",
  "cmnt"   : {"set":"Shy"}
 }
]'
```

Check [Here](http://yonik.com/solr/atomic-updates/) for more details

Comment: Thank you very much, it's work!
But if my data are very large,this will cost a lot of time for iterate, Are there other solutions?

Comment: AS I know you can update part of document in two ways. First Atomic Updates(as I showed in the answer) second is optimistic concurrency. Upvote or accept my answer if you find it usefull. thank you